# Options of Mount Points in Linux

Tags: filesystems, mount

I ran a command `findmount`, and find a list of mount points, but the main problem I have is under the `OPTIONS` column, there are a whole bunch of options, that I don't have much of a clue of what they mean or do. I tried searching some, but found nothing so far.

Here is what I am referring to:

```
# findmnt --output OPTIONS
OPTIONS
rw,ndspid,ddzd=6ZZ3Pi,eode=7Z5F|3Z<<pdoc/scdnd_dedug:pt[n...
```

FSTYPE: `tmpfs`

Is there any sort of documentation or anything, maybe I am not sure what exactly to look for?

Comment: `man mount` would be your first point of call. But just take a look at them and see what many of them means, it's not difficult.

Comment: Did that right now and see them. Thanks

Comment: ok update.. I tried searching for `ndspid`, `ddzd`,`eode`, but none of them showed up

Comment: Those option are going to be specific to the relevent filesystem, and should be documented with the fs. For example `man ext4`.

Comment: Then check on the fstype man page, ie `man mount.<fstype>`. Those 3 options listed do look a little strange and perhaps an update to your question saying what the fstype is would help.

Comment: I tried that, couldn't find it, fstype is `tmpfs`

Comment: This looks like garbled output. None of these options except rw appear to make sense. Perhaps OP's environment is special (emulation, embedded) and something goes wrong because of it.

Comment: I recently got on the system, upon enumerating the system it was a docker container, they have some documentation related to `tmpfs`. I might post an answer to this after a while. It was weird seeing output like that, so I decided to put up a question here. You are right about the about the environment.